# Ruby variable regular expression in Array Select

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, select

I'm trying to exclude elements from an array of strings using `array.select`. I have this method:

```
def filter_out_other_bad_vals(array_of_strs, things_i_want)
  array_of_strs = array_of_strs.select { |line| /"#{things_i_want}"/.match(line) } 
end
```

I want to pass a string as a variable `things_i_want`. But this does not return any matches:

```
array = ["want_this", "do_not_want", "do_not_want","want_this", "want_this"]
pattern = 'want_this'
array = filter_out_other_bad_vals(array, pattern)
```

This returns an empty array. But if I hardcode the value in the match expression, I get what I want.

```
def filter_out_other_bad_vals(array_of_strs, things_i_want)
  array_of_strs = array_of_strs.select { |line| /want_this/.match(line) } 
end
```

How do I put a variable in the regex? What am I doing wrong?

I could just traverse the array, check each item, and then save the value in another array, but that's not very ruby-like, is it?

Comment: if you wanted to filter based on regexp (given question is not clear), then you can use `array.grep(/want_this/)` or `pattern = /want_this/` followed by `array.grep(pattern)` ... to get other than matching elements, use `grep_v` instead of `grep`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You include quotes in regex definition:

```
 /"#{things_i_want}"/
```

remove them and it should work:

```
/#{things_i_want}/
```

EDIT:
By the way, you don't have to use regex for exact matching, you can use equality check (`==`) or `#include?` depending if you need a string to be equal to thing you want or just include it:

```
> array = ["want_this", "do_not_want", "do_not_want","want_this", "want_this"]
> array.select{|line| line == 'want_this'}
# => ["want_this", "want_this", "want_this"]
> array.select{|line| line.include? 'want_this'}
# => ["want_this", "want_this", "want_this"]
```

Comment: Jose, note that `"do_not_want_this".match?(/want_this/) #=> true`. If `false` is desired here add anchors (`/\Awant_this\z/`, where `\A` and `\z` are the  beginning and end of string), or, better, as suggested in this answer, simply `line == 'want_this'`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't trying to get exact matches. The context is some ruby that parses a DNS zone-transfer query. The CNAMES that it was returning had unwanted results...long story. I thought I'd simplify my coding sample.